# If A is a subset of B, how do we know that their intersection is A?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given that:

### $A\subset B$

How do we know that:

### $A\cap B = A$

and are there any other rules related to subsets, that influence the typical intersection, union, and complement operations?

I was calculating $P(B|A)$ and the relationship above tripped me up.

Comment: Draw a picture.

Comment: Drawing the picture helped.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course every element of the intersection of $A$ and $B$ is an element of $A$. $$A\supseteq A\cap B$$

Now, the meaning of set $A$ being a subset of set $B$, is that every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$.   From that we can infer that every element of $A$ is an element of $A$ and of $B$. $$A\subseteq B ~\implies~ A\subseteq A\cap B$$

Thus we can conclude that the set $A$ equals the intersection of $A$ and $B$. $$\therefore~~A\subseteq B ~\implies~ A = A\cap B$$